# Java robot executable jar file not working as expected

Tags: java, lag, awtrobot

I have this code in eclipse, and when I run it, the robot clicks but doesn't move the mouse. However, when I exported it as a executable .jar file, whenever it clicks, the mouse moves to the spot where it originated when I moved it.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Robot r= new Robot();

            while(true){
                r.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
                Thread.sleep(300);
                r.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
                Thread.sleep(300);


            }
        } catch (AWTException | InterruptedException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran this code as a executable jar and it worked fine.

Comment: Is it platform specific? I'm using Mac Sierra 10.12.6 with java 8

Comment: May be. I am using Windows 10.